# How do I use WAMP?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I can easily connect to local host and my LAN IP both on port 80 and 8080, but my external IP is having connectivity issues. I cannot connect to it by just typing my external IP or even by typing a port number, I've read countless of articles and google didn't help me because I don't have the same problems as the people asking the questions.

When I type my external IP address with and without a port extension it gives me nothing except a "Problem loading page". I followed many advice and tips i even uninstalled it and reinstalled it and still cannot connect to my external IP. It's irritating because I port forwarded my IP, i know my port forwarding works because I can play any game on any port. But My WAMP is being stubborn for some reason.

I clicked on put online and that should've worked. But I'm at a pause at the moment in my website development. So i know my webpage isn't corrupted because it works like a charm locally, which thank goodness that was easier than hosting it online. If anyone has an idea as to why this is happening, help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Nope, its removed from my computer. I only use COMODO Security.

Comment: well you cant actually remove it - I assume you mean you turned it off

Comment: That's what they tell you ;)

Comment: also, on the side note: It's not firewall, it's not the WAMP server (or it would connect and give me an error), it just simple doesn't load..